# Get element text behind shadow DOM element using Playwright

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I am trying to use Playwright to get contents of the open shadow root element which looks like this.

```
<some-element>
  #shadow-root
  ABC
</some-element>
```

Here `#shadow-root` contains text `ABC` without any additional tags.

I am able to locate `some-element` but I cannot find a way to get the contents of `#shadow-root`

Example Python code I am using is below:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.firefox.launch(args=["--disable-gpu"], headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://www.sample.com")
    some_element = page.locator('some-element')
    ...
    # ???
```

Playwright [docs](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/selectors) state that their selectors can choose elements in shadow DOM, but examples contain only options where `shadow-root` contains other tags.

How do I get the contents of `#shadow-root` if it only contains the text, without any tags ?

Comment: Can you paste the piece of html to see the example please? The real html please, thank you!

Comment: @JakyRuby Here it is: https://imgur.com/C2Fuv4I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locator will help you find an element. But from there, if you don't have an element to pierce the Shadow DOM, you might need to do that manually.

```
text = page.locator('some-element').first.evaluate("node => node.shadowRoot.innerHTML")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a demo page which have the same behavior than your page has: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/shadow-selection-polyfill/demo.html

[image]

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(args=["--disable-gpu"], headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://googlechromelabs.github.io/shadow-selection-polyfill/demo.html")
    print(page.evaluate("document.querySelector('#host1').shadowRoot.childNodes[0].data"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but your locator is selecting inner html of the `<div id="host1">` element, not the contents of its `#shadow-root`
On your url `#shadow-root` contains this text: `  I'm some content in the DOM`. How do you get it ?

Comment: This answer looks correct, and should work fine on OP's example. "I'm some content in the DOM" isn't part of the shadow root in the example page (you can see the root is collapsed in the screenshot). "This text starts with extra whitespace, and contains an ignored <style> node right after this." is the child text directly within the shadow root, which this code produces.